# Binding in code to my property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've been trying to write a lil' chess game and it came to my mind that I'd like to display threat count on the fields to help me debug. However it doesn't work, i.e. the Text property stays "", and I have no clue why.

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; i++)
{
      for (int j = 0; j < grid.RowDefinitions.Count; j++)
      {
          ...
          TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
          Binding binding = new Binding("WhiteThreats");
          binding.Source = game.board[i][j];
          textBlock.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
          ...
      }
}
```

where game.board[i][j] is of type GameField specified as follows:

```
struct GameField : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    private int whiteThreats;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int WhiteThreats
    {
        get { return whiteThreats;}
        set
        {
            whiteThreats = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("WhiteThreats"));
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I've checked every other possibilities that came to my mind. The TextBox is displayed correctly, and the binding.Source is also correctly assigned. I am stuck now.

Comment: you used [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) and verified DataContext is assigned correctly? also check the actual property in Snoop to see if it has a Binding error.

Comment: That is indeed a very nice tool. Shame I did not know it before. I solved my problem, it appears that I have misstyped TextBlock for TextBox in SetBinding ... ow dear. Thanks a lot.

Comment: ......i deleted my comment because you found out.